# Is there a chashash of sheidim with liquids other than water?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, chasidut-hasidism

There are many people who spill out water (at least in chassidic circles) before drinking it based off of a statement in Gemoro Brochos if I remember correctly that says water left uncovered gains a sakono from shaidim or snakes squirting venom. I've never seen anyone pour out beer, but the Sefer Zochur L'Avrohom about the previous Toldos Aharon rebbe zy"a states that one should be concerned on fluids on the whole, because even though there may not be snakes spitting venom in our water sources anymore, there are still ta'amim al pi sod.

So, my question for the Mi Yodeya kehilla is if there are any mekoros for us to worry about fluids such as wine, beer, seltzer, or anything other than water in traditional sources in regards to shaidim?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/97416/759

Comment: @dou yes, seems so

Comment: Uncovered is clearly forbidden, but I'm asking on still covered. Per example, I know many people who will pour out even if it's coming from a bottle, or one of those water dispensers they have in many shulen, or hot water from a samovar before making coffee.

Comment: @yyb896 Isn’t seltzer also [carbonated] water?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Leaving drink out over night](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/97416/leaving-drink-out-over-night)

Comment: See mishna trumot chapter 8 not adressed to shedim but to snake venom